# ¿Puedo subir imágenes en el chat?

Tags: soporte, privilegios, chat

Estoy en un chat y la otra persona tiene la posibilidad de pasarme una imagen de cómo se ve el código por medio de fotos. Esta persona me dice que al lado de *send* está el botón para subir, pero a mí no me aparece

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y siempre está la opcion de subirla a un repositorio de imágenes y compartir la url

Comment: @lois6b o ir a publicar una pregunta o respuesta, dar a añadir imagen y luego copiar el enlace que generó imgur.

Comment: @fedorqui pues si, usé muchas veces eso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como se explica en el Centro de ayuda, en la descripción del [privilegio de creación de salas de chat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), se necesita un mínimo de 100 puntos para poder subir imágenes:

> **¿Qué otros privilegios nuevos en el chat obtengo?**
>
> Con 100 de reputación también accedes al botón "Subir imagen" en el chat.

Answer (score 2):

Si estás usando *Google Chrome*, puedes mostrar el botón con la siguiente línea en la consola de *JavaScript*:

```js
$("#upload-file").show()
```

[image: imagen]

Comment: Espero que ésta no sea la solución. Sería un agujero de seguridad interesante.

Comment: Creo que se como, pero necesito el codigo html del boton el cual se ve cuando se le da en inspeccionar